# emacs like fill-paragraph option in textmate?

Tags: macos, textmate

Is there an option to reformat lines/paragraphs/selected text to 80 cols in TextMate like in emacs (fill-paragraph bound to M-q)?  If not, do you know of any option to add this to TextMate - a known plugin/macro?  any help in writing such a macro is most welcome too. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only changes how the text is displayed — not the text itself — but in the menu bar, "View" > "Wrap Column" > "78". Or choose "Other…", it displays a vertical ruler you can move to the desired column.

If the "Soft Wrap" option is checked, your text will **look** like it's reformated.

To reformat the text for real, simply hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>. It will use the number checked in the aforementioned menu.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to hard-wrap paragraphs see here: http://lists.macromates.com/textmate/2006-November/015707.html